# Redirect output and error in to both logfile and console in #/bin/sh

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, cron, shell-exec

I want shell script output and error to be redirected to both file and  console
I use `#/bin/sh` and the following works in BASH but not in base shell (`#/bin/sh`). Any ways to achieve this in `#/bin/sh`?

```
set -x

exec > >(tee "logfile") 2>&1
```

And exec &> logfile will output only to file and not to standard output

Comment: Shouldn't that be `#!/bin/sh` not `#/bin/sh`?

Comment: Yeah, that is correct #!/bin/sh only I use

Answer (score 2):

```
 /path/2/cmd 2>&1 | tee logfile
```

Is as old school as you can get.

IHTH